# Populate several PDF forms with customer info that's emailed to me?

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I work outside all day I measure and install doors! My job sends me a purchase order with customer info: name, address, phone and purchase order number, I then have to enter this info on five different PDF forms for same customer, 15 to 25 customers a week! for what I understand so far I will be purchasing acrobat pro. can you guys point me in the right direction with the software and coding I need to get familiar with to achieve this. thank you in advance.

I enter other info on these forms manually on the job but I'm hoping to use a tablet and creating drop down boxes in the future.

[image: user form send to PDF forms]

Answer (score 0):

I've made something similar in the past using Excel 2013.

You don't need acrobat pro. This can be done within Excel itself using just VBA forms and code to export the PDF as an email or to save it on a specified drive.

1) Look up a guide to create a VBA user form in Excel. 
2) Google how to transfer input on the form to the excel worksheet. 
3) The excel worksheet is your form you want to save/send to the customers.
4) Google code to save the worksheet as PDF/Send the Worksheet as PDF to an email or drive. 
5) Look at data that is used across all your forms and make it so you only have to enter it once in as many places as possible. This will save you the most time.

If you need any help, message me and I'll help you get it up and running.

Comment: Thank you vbajames, I added an image link to original post of a user form I made from your suggestion now I have to populate these PDF forms with this info, there is other things and forms to fill out on the job site etc, for now this is a good start.

Comment: The fillable Pdf forms I want to populate were made by some else a few years ago I just put the customer info and field notes and send to office by email